# DatabaseError: Data truncated for column 'raw_value' at row 1

Tags: python, mysql

So I am inserting data measurements into my MySQL database and sometimes I have null values that need to be inserted. Bu I always get the same error and I don't understand why. If the value isn't None, the measurement is inserted, but not the other way around.

This is the part of the code where a measurement is inserted.

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO `measurement` (`station_id`, `metric_name`, `raw_value`, `corrected_value`, `quality`, `failure`, `failure_type`, `timestamp`) " + \
        "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);")

if str(message["failure"]) == False:
    failure = 0
else:
    failure = 1

if str(message["true_value"]) == None:
    cursor.execute(sql, (str(sensor_id[0][0]), metric, None, str(message["value"]), str(message["quality"]), failure, message["failure_type"], timestamp))
else:
    cursor.execute(sql, (str(sensor_id[0][0]), metric, str(message["true_value"]), str(message["value"]), str(message["quality"]), failure, message["failure_type"], timestamp))
```

This is the error I get:

```
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'raw_value' at row 1
```

Column `raw_value` is configured as a double in the database.

Comment: what does `str(message["true_value"])` contain and what's the data type of the raw_value column?

Comment: @jordanm message["true_value"] is a float like 23.05. But it can sometimes be None. the raw_value column receives that value and its data type is a double

Comment: `str(None)` returns the string `"None"`. You get this warning because "None" is not a double. Mysql usually does something weird here and turns the string into a number before giving you this warning. If you want to set `null` in the DB, you need pass actual `None` and not `str(None)`.

Comment: @jordanm isn't that what I'm doing in the code I posted?

Comment: You're right, i overlooked that. Can `message["value"]` also be None?